# How to generate a image that contains a matrix like this in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

[image]

Suppose we have a 0-1 matrix, I want to generate a picture that is white in 0 entry and black in 1 entry, like the picture above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `imagesc()`, with a gray colormap:

```
n = 10; % size of your matrix
a = randi(2, n, n) - 1; % random matrix containing only 1s and 0s

imagesc(a)
colormap gray
```

Comment: Is there a command that can add grid line?

Comment: Check [`grid`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/grid.html).

Comment: `grid` may not produce the lines coinciding with cell borders. [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) does that, but it ignores the last row and column of the input. So you can use `pcolor(a([1:end 1], [1:end 1])), axis ij`